# convert arabic unicode to string to store at mysql in python and read data in lua

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, utf-8, lua

I have a var unicode came from scrapy in python and i have stored this in mysql. I have tried all of ways in web to encode to `utf-8` and converted my unicode to string with this way

`unicode.encode('utf-8')`

and store to db with this connection in python file

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="", 
                     user="", 
                     passwd="",
                     db="",
                     cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,
                     charset='utf8',
                     init_command='SET NAMES UTF8'
                     )
```

then i read data from mysql in lua with this code

```
local env = assert (luasql.mysql())
local con = assert (env:connect("","",""))
local cursor,errorString = assert (con:execute("SELECT `id`,`arabic_name`,`arabic_lastname` FROM `user_info`"))
local row = cursor:fetch ({}, "a")
```

when i print result of row in while loop . it returns to me `????` type of string.
I tried this way in python and returned me again `????` ,
but in phpmyadmin i have seen columns with correct type of string.
i guess mysql library in lua and python can not return correct type of arabic string.

Anybody know how i can solve this problem and problem where ? in store data or read data!

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in python or lua?

Comment: I want read records in lua .python  is for writing and lua for reading in this project .  i set mysql table and collection to utf8_general_ci

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read data from luasql with utf8 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966247/read-data-from-luasql-with-utf8-format)

Comment: Answers to last question is not work and nessery for me solve this problem

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  And, if possible, the hex of the data you are trying to store.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `SET NAMES cp1256` in order to declare that the *client* bytes are encoded CP1256?

The table's *columns* could then be either `utf8` or `cp1256` and the transcoding would be done by MySQL during `INSERT` and `SELECT`.